Determining concavity of a certain function
Let $t\in(0,1)$ be a fixed number. Consider the function $f(x)=2\cos(t)\arccos(\cot(t)(\csc(x)-\cot(x)))+\arccos(\csc^2(t)\cos(x)-\cot^2(t))$. I believe that this function is concave down for $x\in(0,2t)$, i.e., $f''(x)<0$ for all $x\in(0,2t)$, but I haven't managed to show it, despite several unsuccessful attempts. It seems delicate but maybe I am completely missing something. How to prove this directly?
This problem came up in a project I am working on with an undergraduate student.

No, it's a single variable function of x. Since t is fixed, the terms involving t are constant. We did plot the entire family (for $0<t<1$) using a slider in Desmos and verified graphically that the statement is true. But we are having trouble proving it analytically. The second derivative is a sum of 4 terms, 1 positive and 3 negative. Numerically experimenting, we found that it seems one needs all 3 negative terms to outweigh the positive one.

It is easy if you use CAS (Computer Algebra System) e.g. Maple to simplify the expressions.

Interesting, thank you for the suggestion. We will try this.
